# Calculating odds of making a hand at any point in the game

Tags: odds

I'm creating a live odds tracker and need to know the odds of making every possible hand at any point in the game, the information I have is:

```
Number of Outs
Number of cards left in the deck
Cards needed to make hand
```

I need to know how to combine these 3 elements in an equation to calculate the odds of making the hand, a flush in this case, so for example pre-flop, with 3 players and cards dealt to me being Jc Qc it would be:

```
Number of Outs - 11
Number of cards left in the deck - 46
Cards needed to make hand - 3
```

So far I have the following equations that I've found in other articles but I'm unsure how to combine them to do what I want:

```
    'The % chance of getting an out of the next hand can be calculated by (outs / remaining cards) * 100
    'To calculate the chance of getting 1 out on the turn or the river do the calculation above for each and add them together (3 / 45 = 0.0666) + (3 / 44 = 0.0681) = 0.1348 * 100 = 13.48%
    'To calculate the chance of getting 2 outs on the turn & river multiply the calculations by each other instead ((3 / 45 = 0.0666) * (3 / 44 = 0.0681) = 0.0045 * 100 = 0.45%
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean by _number of outs_?  Why would being dealt JcQc mean you have 11 outs?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question to show that I'm looking to make a flush, so with 13 cards in a suit, 2 of which I already have there are 11 left of that suit and I need 3 of them to make a flush.

Comment: Do you need precisely three of your suit on the board, or would four or five also be favourable?

Comment: I queried [suited cards making flush by the river](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=suited+cards+making+flush+by+the+river) on Google and I am more than confident that you will find an answer among the first few hits.

Comment: No as long as it's at least 3 thats fine.

Comment: Also, "number of cards left in deck" is not useful. You need number of cards *you haven't seen*. Probability is a measure if *information*, so what's important is what you know and don't know. Whether the unseen cards are left in the deck, or your opponents' hands, or the burns, is not relevant.

Comment: I'm not just looking for the calculation for this particular hand, as per the title I'm looking for the calculation for any hand based on those 3 variables.

Comment: There would be no way to completely answer your question.  For example, you are dealt 78s.  How would you know what your outs are if you don't have any _guesses_ (reads) on your opponent and his range?  You could be drawing dead to a higher FD, in which case the suited cards coming would not be considered outs.  You could be against an overpair, which means just pairing one of your cards is insufficient.  You could be dominating against 73o, in which case you don't need any outs but only need to fade a 3.

Comment: "number of cards left in deck" is the same thing as number of cards I haven't seen and is integral to the calculation I think i.e there are 45 cards left in the deck and 11 of them are clubs to the chance of being dealt a club next is 11 / 45 = 24.4%

Comment: How would you know 11 of them are clubs?  There may be as few as 7 if you have two other opponents.

Comment: If you want to look more into this subject, I highly recommend [The PokerStrategy.com Equilab](https://www.pokerstrategy.com/poker-software-tools/equilab-holdem/).  It uses [Monte Carlo simulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) to make a really accurate estimate of probabilities.

Comment: Andrew, for the purposes of this question it's irrelevant what the other player may or may not have, I just want a % chance of making a specific hand based on the cards I have and the cards yet to be dealt. Maybe I should have posted this in the Math group instead.

Comment: Yes to maybe I should of posted in the math group instead. There are generally more poker programming posts in other programming/math groups then tend to get posted here. Search on gaming simulations, gaming theory, things like that. You will also find good shuffle and hand reading simulations. While many of us here program the focus here tends to be on playing the game.